# Show that if $f: X \to Y$ is injective and $y \in Y$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ contains at most one point

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Show that if $f: X \to Y$ is injective and $y \in Y$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ contains at most one point

This seemed very straightforward, but I cannot seem to be able to show this rigorously... If I pick $p,q\in X$ I have that $f^{-1}(f(p)) = \{p\}$ right? So I would get that $$f(p)=f(q) \\ f^{-1}(f(p)) = f^{-1}(f(q)) \\ \{p\} = \{q\} \\ p=q$$ is this anywhere in the direction I would need to go? It seems that I don't want to show that the function is actually injective here since that's given to me, I would need to show that the cardinality of $f^{-1}(y)$ is $1$ right?

Comment: Where you say "right" you mean "wrong". Look again at the definition of $f^{-1}(A)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y\in Y$, then if $f^{-1}(y)$ contains more than one point we have that $p,q \in f^{-1}(y), p\not= q \implies f(p) = y = f(q)$ that is a contradiction because $f$ is an injective function. Then $f^{-1}(y)$ contains one point or none

Comment: Well, this was rather straightforward. However, I assume there is a way to show this also without striving for contradiction?

Comment: Without contradiction... If $f^{-1}(y) = \emptyset$ we are done. If $p\in f^{-1}(y) \implies f(p) = y$. Then if another point $q \in f^{-1}(y)$ we have that $f(q) = y = f(p) \implies p = q$ because $f $ is an injective function. Then $f^{-1}(y) = \{p\}$